# Why does GNU say it is "Not Unix"?

Tags: history, gnu

I use Fedora. Today I found GNU (on the web) about which I didn't know till yesterday. I knew that GNU is a Unix-like operating system that is free software but I didn't get why they say GNU's "Not Unix".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix

Comment: @Anthon I know Unix but in-spite of a Unix-like system, why GNU say "Not Unix"?

Comment: If you have a different question about what you did not get, don't post it in a comment, post it as a new question. Your post clearly and unambiguously asks two times for the same thing: "What is meant by **Unix** in GNU's not Unix", so if you follow the link that will answer your question.

Comment: @user166847 See if my edit is in accord with what you meant to ask.

Comment: @Anthon I've revised the post. Does it look clear now?

Comment: @user166847 No it is not more clear. 1) the body of your post has no question (at least the original post had one although a completely different one from what is now in your title only). 2) What is the relevance of you using Fedora? 3) You should IMO leave out non-relevant fluff about that you found GNU on the web blah blah 4) Writing "I learn that" sounds wrong to me (but then I am not a native speaker). 5) I would always include where you get "Not UNIX" from not everyone coming here knows what GNU stands for.

Comment: The name of the system, GNU, is a recursive acronym meaning GNU's Not Unix—a way of paying tribute to the technical ideas of Unix, while at the same time saying that GNU is something different. Technically, GNU is like Unix. But unlike Unix, GNU gives its users freedom. - [About GNU](http://www.gnu.org/gnu/about-gnu.html)

Comment: The name acknowledges that GNU learned from Unix's technical design, but also importantly notes that they are unrelated. Unlike Unix, GNU is Free Software. - [FSFE](http://fsfe.org/freesoftware/basics/gnuproject.en.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The recursive acronym of GNU "GNU's Not Unix!" was chosen because, while GNU's design is Unix-like, it differs from it by being free software.

The original Unix was closed-source, so all of the GNU code has been entirely rewritten and does not contain any of the original Unix code.

Comment: OK; I got that they say "Not Unix" because it is free unlike Unix, plus doesn't contain any Unix code!

Comment: It seems text is taken from wikipedia article on [GNU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU)!

Comment: Yes, this information is taken from Wikipedia.  I didn't directly quote it since I wanted to add some more information.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the GNU code has been *rewritten*, as that implies the code is derived from the Unix source code. GNU was written without ever having had any Unix source code in it. It is functionally Unix-like, but not genetically Unix-like (like the BSDs).